# .getBoundingClientRect() not changing values on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a side pagination bar, and I want it to change colors when different parts of the page come into view, so I am using the .getBoundingClientRect in javascript. However, everytime I scroll, the position of the element is the same in the console logs, even if I have scrolled all the way to the bottom.

Can someone help me so that the values change when they are meant to?

```js
var aboutPage = document.getElementById('about');
var aboutBounding = aboutPage.getBoundingClientRect();

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

    console.log(aboutBounding);

    if (
        aboutBounding.top >= 0 &&
        aboutBounding.left >= 0 &&
        aboutBounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
        aboutBounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
        console.log('In the viewport!');
    } else {
        console.log('Not in the viewport... whomp whomp');
    }
})
```

```css
/* SIDE PAGEINTATION */

.side-pagination {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 72px;
  height: 138px;
  width: 24px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

.page-circle {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-circle.menuactive {
  background-color: var(--secondary-clr);
}

.page-circle:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.page-circle:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.page-circle:nth-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.landing-main-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: gray;
}

.work-main-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: pink;
}

.about-main-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-pagination">
  <div class="page-2 page-circle"></div>
  <div class="page-3 page-circle"></div>
  <div class="page-4 page-circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="landing-main-body">
</div>
<div class="about-main-body" id="about">

</div>
<div class="work-main-body" id="work">

</div>
```

EDIT: I will try using IntersectionObserver in the morning, stay put till then :D.

Comment: To sense when an element comes into the viewport you can use IntersectionObserver.

Comment: I concur with A Haworth; the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is specifically designed to handle the situation of elements entering and leaving the viewport. The `scroll` event listener is an old way to it which can hurt performance of your site.

Comment: @AHaworth  Thank you, I will have to try this as my old method arose to many problems.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks for the info, I will be using this now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store the `getBoundingClientRect` value **outside** the scroll event listener, you're only storing the rect value once. In other words, it won't update as the scroll event fires.

You need to read the `getBoundingClientRect` value **inside** the scroll event listener like so:

```js
var aboutPage = document.getElementById('about');
// var aboutBounding = aboutPage.getBoundingClientRect(); <-- Don't read it here

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

    var aboutBounding = aboutPage.getBoundingClientRect(); // <-- Read it inside the scroll listener
    console.log(aboutBounding);

    if (
        aboutBounding.top >= 0 &&
        aboutBounding.left >= 0 &&
        aboutBounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
        aboutBounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
        console.log('In the viewport!');
    } else {
        console.log('Not in the viewport... whomp whomp');
    }
})
```

As an alternative approach you might want to consider using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to check when an element is in view or not. I find its API easy to understand and simpler to use than the scroll event listener with `getBoundingClientRect` approach.

Comment: This fixed my problem, but because of different issues and compatibility, I have to use a different method, Thank You

Answer (score 2):

`getBoundingClientRect()` is not reactive. You get the result of the `read` operation (at the point in time when you read the value).

By placing

```js
var aboutBounding = aboutPage.getBoundingClientRect();
```

outside of the function, `aboutBounding` will remain the same value it was when it was read.

Move that line inside the function which performs on every `scroll` event and it will start working.

Comment: This fixed my problem, but because of different issues and compatibility, I have to use a different method, Thank You